# Android - Java Equivalent Of iOS Block Callbacks?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

In my Android app, I'd like to implement success and error callbacks for when I get reading passages from my backend. In iOS, it would look like this:

In my Passage.h:

```
-(void)getPassagesWithSuccessCallback:(void (^)(NSArray<Passage *> *))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString *))errorString;
```

In my Passage.m:

```
-(void)getPassagesWithSuccessCallback:(void (^)(NSArray<Passage *> *))success errorCallback:(void (^)(NSString *))errorString {
    MyApiInterface* api = [MyApiInterface sharedInstance];
    [api sendGetRequestTo:@"passages" successCallback:[Passage modelListCallback:success] errorCallback:error];
}
```

In my Android app, I'm using `Volley` to handle my API requests, but I want to further encapsulate this API interfacing by having a Passage.java class with a `public static void` method that gets the passages. Something like this:

```
public static void getPassagesForFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user, Context context) {
        final String url = URL_BASE + "/passages.json" + "?auth=" + user.getToken(false);
        final JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // convert JSON into ArrayList<Passage> object
                // pass on this array of Passages in the success completion listener of the method that called this
                // just like iOS does success(passages)
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // convert error to string
                // pass on this errorString in the error completion listener of the method that called this
                // just like iOS does error(errorString)
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
}
```

Is there any way to get this kind of implementation flow?

Comment: Define an interface for your callback, pass an instance of that into `getPassagesForFirebaseUser()`, and call methods on the callback from `onResponse()` and/or `onErrorResponse()`. IOW, you do exactly what Volley is having you do, by passing instances of `Response.Listener` and `Response.ErrorListener` into the `JsonObjectRequest` constructor.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Your comment and Joa Barcena's answer were very helpful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an Interface

```
public interface ICallbacks { 
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response);
    public void onError(VolleyError error);
}
```

Then in your routine code just put a new instance of Callbacks (depending on ide that you work could autogenerate the methods)

```
public static void getPassagesForFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user,
Context context, ICallbacks events) { 
//here code and call ICallbacks methods
if(result){ events.onResponse(response); }
if(error){ events.onError(err); }
}
```

ultimately you can call the method with :

```
getPassagesForFirebaseUser(user, context, new ICallbacks(){
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response){
        //Success !!!
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(VolleyError response){
        //Error !!!
    }
});
```

Sorry for my English, hope this help !

Comment: So I can do the same thing with, for example, `onResponse(ArrayList<Passage> passage)` and it would work just fine? That's very interesting. Seems like I've been with Objective-C and away from Java for far too long!

Comment: Yes !! you can !!, When I heard that I started using everywhere haha

Comment: @joa Thank you !! This simple example really helps